# JS: How to comment inside a regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex, syntax, comments, language-features

How can I annotate the different parts of a regular expression written across multiple lines? I want to do something like this:

```
'Acts 1:3'.replace(/
    (\w+) //book
    (\d+) //chapter
    :
    (\d+) //verse
/);
```

I am surprised that I am not able to find similar questions on Google or SO.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Ronny/3qky4/7/

Comment: This question is specific enough that you may find it easier to check the actual specification at https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf

Comment: In other regex engines you can use `(?# comment here )` but JavaScript doesn't currently allow this.